# Travis CI gets stuck on starting build tools in Android

Tags: android, travis-ci

I am trying to add Travis CI to my Android project to run tests for me. Currently I am just trying to use the CI to build and clean my project, but it doesn't work, it appears to hang after a while and infinitely repeat things in the logs before eventually erroring out. Here is a sample of the log: https://gist.github.com/AdamMc331/6da4433a047815d8e072bf2b7fb81a44

I am completely baffled by this. I don't know what the issue could be. Below is my .travis.yml file:

```
language: android

android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - build-tools-25.0.2
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - extra-android-support
    - android-25

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
script:
  - chmod +x gradlew
  - ./gradlew clean build --stacktrace --info

licenses:
  - android-sdk-license-.+

notifications:
  email: false

sudo: false

cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.gradle
```

I've tried adding --debug to the gradle task, but it didn't help much. Once the file hits that "trying to start build tools" line, there are no more [DEBUG] statements printed.

If anyone wants to fork the project and try it for themselves, I am using branch CC-46: https://github.com/AdamMc331/CashCaretaker/tree/feature/CC-46 If you look at settings.gradle file you'll notice I'm only using the `utility` and `app-v2` modules right now.

Here is a log file when I run these commands locally in my terminal: https://gist.github.com/AdamMc331/6d0d0575aa170a760c84ad3244aed1b7

You can see that it also tries to start the build tools there, but it doesn't try 15 different times and it will eventually work without erroring out. The travis build must be doing something different.

Comment: there is no "trying to start build tools" line inside log

Comment: It is in the log. 15 times, actually - https://gist.github.com/AdamMc331/6da4433a047815d8e072bf2b7fb81a44#file-log-txt-L11-L35

Comment: ah you meant that.. So the stage mergeDebugResources is never completed or the log file is truncated. Did you try to run the building manually on the same machine with the same command? Did you try to remove "clean" from command (you have custom action on clean in build.gradle - that might cause an error)?

Comment: I can run clean and build locally without any issue, that's part of why I'm so baffled. That leads me to believe there's a difference between my machine and whatever machine Travis is running this on?

Comment: I'll run locally and get a log from my terminal and post that up too, for comparison if it helps anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Travis CI might kill gradle if the building process gets too intense, you may want to increase the memory and add some performance tweaks. Check if that works.

Try this on your `gradle.properties` file:

```
## Project-wide Gradle settings.
#
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
#
# The Gradle daemon aims to improve the startup and execution time of Gradle.
# When set to true the Gradle daemon is to run the build.
org.gradle.daemon=true
#
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
#
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
org.gradle.parallel=true
#
# Enables new incubating mode that makes Gradle selective when configuring projects.
# Only relevant projects are configured which results in faster builds for large multi-projects.
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:configuration_on_demand
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

**Edit:** Try to downgrade your gradle from 3.3.0 to 2.2.3 as it doesn't compile on my projects either.

Comment: I tried this, and I did see a change in the logs that looked like it was working better, but still errors out. Perhaps it's a combination of what you and Anton suggested. I will try his suggestion and let you know. But this definitely helped, +1 for that. :)

Comment: I changed the MaxPermSize again, this time to 1024m and it passed. I am going to go through all of my gradle files one last time to make sure everything is the way I had it originally, and try again. If this works, I will award the bounty.

Comment: Are you able to build any projects using gradle version 3.3.0? Your fix worked for me, but then when I updated gradle again, I got another fail.

Comment: You are definitely right that it worked if gradle version is 2.2.3. Any idea why? Should this be a new question or should I update the current one?

Comment: I believe that it might be a new question. Maybe it's a bug on the new version of gradle, I'm not entirely sure why it works for me :/ sorry.

Comment: Good catch, though. I'll award the bounty since you helped me resolve this for now, but a separate question may be required to understand why 3.3.0 fails.

Answer (score 2):

I found some differences between your `.travis.yml` and working samples. Please try this one:

```
language: android
android:
  components:
    - tools
    - build-tools-25.0.2
    - android-25
    - platform-tools
    - extra-android-support
    - extra-google-google_play_services
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - extra-google-m2repository
  licenses:
    - '.+'

sudo: required

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

before_script:
  - chmod +x gradlew

script:
  - ./gradlew clean build --stacktrace --info
```

I think the problem could be with license checks or requiring sudo, or (less expected) script section.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will give this a try. I'm not using google_play_services, but it shouldn't matter if the travis file has it, right? What I'm really asking is, it won't break anything, it will just be an unnecessary operation?

Comment: I would rather keep that extra-google-google_play_services until the problem is sorted out... Also you include com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0 in https://github.com/AdamMc331/CashCaretaker/blob/feature/CC-46/app/build.gradle

Comment: Oh, good catch, but I'm actually only using the utility and app-v2 modules right now. I will update my question to clarify that, sorry!

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but that didn't appear to work, either.

Comment: Please also add `after_failure: "cat $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/app/build/outputs/lint-results-debug.xml"` into .travis.yml and update build log